# ZFS 2.0: How can I lower CPU-load on write with very slow disks and weak CPU?

Tags: performance, zfs, zfsonlinux, arm

I have a small 32bit-ARM-based board with three disk attached via USB 2.0.  This has been running fine with ZFS 0.7.1 and 0.6.x for a long time, and I do not mind the reduced disk performance. (I am using ZFS elsewhere, I like to have this compatible and available when the real servers go down).  However, I had to upgrade the distribution, 0.7.1 does not install nicely anymore, 0.8.5/6 is not stable under load, but 2.0.1 is completely stable again (<strike>features are still 0.7.1 compatible</strike>).  I am not using ZVOLs on this device, just regular datasets.

My problem: The CPU load gets very high on writes.  I am under the impression that the slow disks cause the CPU load and iowaits to increase massively causing other tasks on the CPU to get interrupted too.  I had a look at this [guide](https://openzfs.org/wiki/ZFS_on_high_latency_devices) which addresses latency, but that does not solve my problem.

Which ZFS parameters should I address, if I know my theoratical maximum write rates, to avoid high CPU-loads?

Comment: How are your disks configured? As three separate disks or as a RAID pool?

Comment: @Massimo Raid-Z1, with compression, no de-dup.  datasets with maximum efficiency/minimal features/options. ARC at 256MB, no ZIL, no L2ARC.

Comment: PS: ARC at 256MB, no ZIL, no L2ARC.  The excessive load occurs with just a single client writing big files.

Comment: "Raid-Z1, with compression"... this seems indeed a good recipe for high CPU load on writes.

Comment: @Massimo Remember, the disks are attached over a very slow connection, so compression is useful.  And I do not think that it is a limiting factor: As a quick benchmark, I ran pigz (parallel gzip) which should be only slightly more efficient than lz4 and the throughput is a multiple of the actual write speeds.And as I said, it worked well on old kernels and zfs versions.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: zfs uses certain amount of CPU to process the iops, most of which are compression and checksuming. If you have the CPU not capable of handling the amount needed - you'll get freezes/spikes. Partial solution is to disable compression and set a weaker/faster checksumming algo. You can also play with [disk iops scheduler](https://rollout.io/blog/linux-io-scheduler-tuning/), but this tends to  be more a moral support measure. For academic/testing usage you can also disable ZIL (`zfs set sync=disabled <dataset>`), but for production use this is generally a bad idea.